# Forge Viewer - Markups extension inside of a react app

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use the forge viewer with markups extension inside of a react app and have ran into a problem.

The viewer is docked within a sheet that slides out from the right handside of the page. The first time I open the viewer it works fine, I click the markup icon and can draw an arrow e.g.:

[image: Working on first view]

When I reopen the same document, click the markup icon and draw another arrow, the arrow is huge, like the scale is all wrong:

[image: Not working]

This is the full react component so far

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ReadonlyFormHTMLContainer } from '../../Components/Form/FormComponents';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../GlobalState';

type ForgeViewerProps = {
    id: string;
    fileUrl: string;
    filename: string;
};

let viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D | null | undefined;

// I can't find a type for Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore - if you can find it, replace any with the correct type, if not you are on your own, no intellisense!
let markup: any;

export const ForgeViewer = (props: ForgeViewerProps) => {
    const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const context = useGlobalContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'Local', useADP: false }, () => {
            viewer = new window.Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(containerRef.current!);
            viewer.start();

            viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then(() => {
                viewer!.loadModel(props.fileUrl, viewer!);
                viewer!.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore').then(ext => {
                    markup = ext;
                });
                viewer!.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui');
            });
        });

        return () => {
            console.log('Running clean up');
            viewer?.tearDown();
            viewer?.finish();
            viewer = null;
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <ReadonlyFormHTMLContainer
            title={'Document markup'}
            subtitle={props.filename}
            formErrorMessage=""
            formErrorTitle=""
            onClose={() => context.hideSheet()}
        >
            <div ref={containerRef}></div>{' '}
        </ReadonlyFormHTMLContainer>
    );
};
```

I have imported following modules from npm:

[image: npm modules]

Forge version: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this? As you can see I've tried some clean up code when the component unmounts but I cannot get the viewer to work "normally" after the initial open.

**Edit**
repro link:  https://github.com/philwindsor/forge-repro/blob/master/index.html

Comment: the Forge Viewer uses Three.js r71, maybe that's causing a conflict there (I see you have r103)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves thanks for looking but, those are just type definitions?

Comment: This looks like it could have something to do with the SVG element's `viewBox` settings. The markup extension updates the view-box property during various events to make sure that all the markups are aligned properly with the position/scale of the drawing. Check whether the `viewBox` values change in a significant way when you hide and show the sliding sheet.

Comment: It would also help if there was a live sample that could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PetrBroz i'm currently working on that now for you. will update the question once I have a repro.

Comment: @PetrBroz https://github.com/philwindsor/forge-repro/blob/master/index.html. I have a feeling its the way I am initialising it?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll try and repro it locally and will let you know as soon as I learn more.

Comment: Alright, I found the issue - let me explain the details in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a timing issue.

When you open the viewer for the first time, the markup extension takes some time to download and it is therefore initialized *after* the model has already been loaded. Because of that, the extension knows how to initialize the scale of its markups properly.

When you open the viewer for the second time, the markup extension is already available, and it is loaded and initialized *before* any model is available. And because of that, it cannot configure the "expected" scale.

To resolve the issue, simply load the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` and `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui` extensions *after* the model is loaded, for example:

```js
viewer.loadModel(urn, options, function onSuccess() {
    viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
    viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui");
});
```